# Roomba 400 navigation stack setup

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, create-autonomy, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm using [create_autonomy](http://wiki.ros.org/create_autonomy) driver for my roomba 400 on kinetic, and I want to set up the navigation stack (especially move_base to send goals to the robot and navigate in rviz). The ca_driver running on Raspberry, the gmapping, map server on the PC.
I'm following the [navigation stack tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), and as described in it, first, I need to create a package with the following dependencies:

```
catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep
```

How should I need to fill up the dependencies on which device (RPI or PC) once the ca_driver itself publish a /tf and a /odom topic when I starting it with the following launch:

```
roslaunch ca_driver roomba_400.launch
```

Maybe if anyone successfully deployed the navigation stack, can send me a sample/example launch file or project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287395/roomba-400-navigation-stack-setup/) by [Ezredes](https://answers.ros.org/users/32851/ezredes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khallad](https://answers.ros.org/users/73585/khallad/) on 2021-04-21**:
Hello!
Did you solve this problem? I'm stuck here and the tutorial for the turtlebot didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in a [previous post](https://answers.ros.org/question/226255/help-with-ros-navigation-stack-create2/?answer=226280#post-id-226280), you can check out [turtlebot_navigation](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation) for example launch and config files.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-06-06**:
so do I need my_sensor_configuration_dep if I am using urg_node? also doesn't the create_autonomy provide tf and odom so that dependency would be move_base urg_node and create_autonomy?